# Upscale an SVG image in python without losing its quality

Tags: python, image, svg, pygame, resize

I have an image in *svg* format of height and width 45 i want to upscale it to 75 is it possible to do without losing quality in pygame.

The image before resizing:

[image]

The image after resizing:

[image]

The code I used to resize:

```
pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('bP.svg'),(75,75))
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 in this case the source is in SVG format, which is vector.  If you resize it before converting to raster it should be perfect.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, how can I do that?

Comment: Not sure, I've never worked with SVG in Python before.

Comment: using ```pygame.image.load``` works for me

Comment: @JohanJomy I see. It seems to be a new but undocumented feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) is a text format. You can edit the SVG file and add a global scale (see [SVG/Transformationen](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/SVG/Transformationen)). e.g.:

```xml
<svg
    transform="scale(2)"
    ...
>
```

---

Since 2.0.2, SDL Image supports SVG files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore with pygame version 2.0.1, [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) supports SVG files.
The scaling must be done when the Scalable Vector Graphic is rendered in a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). It would be nice to have a *scale* or *size* argument in `pygame.image.load()`. However, something like this is not documented (yet).

---

A work around is to load the SVG text and to add the scaling (`transform="scale(2)"`). The string can be load into a binary I/O buffer with the [`io` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html). Finally, this buffered and scaled SVG can be loaded with [`pygame.image.laod`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load):

```py
import io

def load_and_scale_svg(filename, scale):
    svg_string = open(filename, "rt").read()
    start = svg_string.find('<svg')    
    if start > 0:
        svg_string = svg_string[:start+4] + f' transform="scale({scale})"' + svg_string[start+4:]
    return pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(svg_string.encode()))

bP_surface = load_and_scale_svg('bP.svg', 2)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import io

def load_and_scale_svg(filename, scale):
    svg_string = open(filename, "rt").read()
    start = svg_string.find('<svg')    
    if start > 0:
        svg_string = svg_string[:start+4] + f' transform="scale({scale})"' + svg_string[start+4:]
    return pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(svg_string.encode()))

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame_surface = load_and_scale_svg('Ice.svg', 0.4)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((127, 127, 127))
    window.blit(pygame_surface, pygame_surface.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: transform="scale(x,y)" if anyone needs to scale x and y independently

Answer (score 2):

this should help with upscaling as it uses a bilinear filter:

`pygame.transform.smoothscale(pygame.image.load('bP.svg'),(75,75))`

Comment: not the best but better than before